# R fastest way to sum 2 characters vectors in data.frame columns and calculate angle

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data.frame with 2 columns:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("3.6854756000000001848,-6.4375996000000004216,8.8997513999999995349",
                        "1.8968172299999999098,-5.4934801999999995914,1.5116269712000001135"),
                 v2 = c("2.8782294999999997742,-2.5761130000000000972,3.0410891000000002116",
                        "2.1329812999999999690,-9.3830139999999992995,7.5242144999999993615"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$vsum <- as.numeric(df$v1) + as.numeric(df$v2)
# get warning and NA values in vsum column
```

I want to get sum of this vectors in column vsum with fastest method (maybe using data.table package) because in initial data I have millions of this rows.

Also I need to calculate angle between this vectors in column theta:

```
theta <- acos( sum(v1*v2) / ( sqrt(sum(v1 * v1)) * sqrt(sum(v2 * v2)) ) )
```

Comment: Works fine for me, although the quotes are weird, the result is probably worthless.

Comment: is your code working now? what is 'fast'?

Comment: @user2974951 its not working your summing factor levels

Comment: @AndreElrico Yes the result is crap, but it works, there are no warnings.

Comment: Fix your data import/creation.

Comment: @Wimpel fast means maximum speed - less than one second for millions rows (if it possible).

Comment: @Roland on my R version 3.5.1 I get in column vsum 2 rows with NA values, but I need integer vector with sum of elements in character vector v1 and v2

Comment: Further clarifying my previous comment: You absolutely should not have character vectors like this. Import your data in a way that creates a sane data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read about [stringsAsFactors](https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/)

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("3.6854756000000001848,-6.4375996000000004216,8.8997513999999995349",
                            "1.8968172299999999098,-5.4934801999999995914,1.5116269712000001135"),
                     v2 = c("2.8782294999999997742,-2.5761130000000000972,3.0410891000000002116",
                            "2.1329812999999999690,-9.3830139999999992995,7.5242144999999993615"),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

possibly one of the faster solutions out there:

```
sum(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(df, strsplit, ","))))
#[1] 7.679979
```

---

as @Roland states in the comment. The main problem is not summing numbers here. The problem is your numbers are pasted as strings with "," as delimiter. See if you can much earlier in your workflow prevent this "illness".

---

If you cannot prevent the strange input format, your first step could look like:

```
df_numerics <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {as.numeric(unlist(lapply(x, strsplit, ",")))}))
```

---

Should be sufficiently fast:

```
theta <- with( df_numerics,
               acos( sum(v1*v2) / ( sqrt(sum(v1 * v1)) * sqrt(sum(v2 * v2)) ) )
               )
#[1] 0.7876798
```

If not, you possibly have to call c, c++ and/or go parallel.

Comment: could you provide some code example for transform this initial data into right R vector format?

Comment: also I need calc angle between this 2 vectors `theta <- acos( sum(v1*v2) / ( sqrt(sum(v1 * v1)) * sqrt(sum(v2 * v2)) ) )` , any idea how implement this in most efficient way?

Comment: @KonstantinTaranov I updated my answer for the last time :-)